# Разговор ни о чем (глагол)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какими словами можно охарактеризовать разговор без толку, ни о чем?

Судачить - нет?

Answer (score 2):

Судачить - это всё-таки не **ни о чём** - это обсуждать кого-то, сплетничать. Говорить ни о чём - **болтать, балагурить, пустословить**. Если возможна разговорная лексика или просторечная, то таких глаголов много:   переливать из пустого в порожнее, чесать язык, трепать языком, точить балясы,   разводить тары-бары, пустозвонить,  заниматься словоблудием.

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется глалол, то по отношению к детям и женщинам употребимо "болтать", ко взрослым мужчинам - "трепаться".